# Error CS0103: The name 'TimeSpan' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (testingProgram)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am trying to create tests in C# with selenium driver in visual studio. I get the following error. Error CS0103: The name 'TimeSpan' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (testingProgram) ?? I also have a second error displayed in the images provided. The code uses the PageObjectPattern >> https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/

Btw I am using a mac. I have added some images to help better describe the situation.The following images show both files. Can someone please try to run in on their end to see if it works.

How do I fix this? Can someone try and run the program to see if it is running on their end?? How do I get this program to run successfully?

[image]
[image]

here is the following code-

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

[TestClass]
public class SearchEngineTests
{
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }
    public WebDriverWait Wait { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        this.Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        this.Wait = new WebDriverWait(this.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        this.Driver.Quit();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SearchTextInSearchEngine_First()
    {
        SearchEngineMainPage searchEngineMainPage = new SearchEngineMainPage(this.Driver);
        searchEngineMainPage.Navigate();
        searchEngineMainPage.Search("Automate The Planet");
        searchEngineMainPage.ValidateResultsCount("264,000 RESULTS");
    }
}
```

here is the second file-

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

public class SearchEngineMainPage
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;
    private readonly string url = @"searchEngineUrl";


    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sb_form_q")]
    public IWebElement SearchBox { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "sb_form_go")]
    public IWebElement GoButton { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "b_tween")]
    public IWebElement ResultsCountDiv { get; set; }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.url);
    }

    public void Search(string textToType)
    {
        this.SearchBox.Clear();
        this.SearchBox.SendKeys(textToType);
        this.GoButton.Click();
    }

    public void ValidateResultsCount(string expectedCount)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(this.ResultsCountDiv.Text.Contains(expectedCount), "The results DIV doesn't contains the specified text.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so, in both cases, the error message tells you exactly what's missing.

First, `TimeSpan` is in the `System` namespace, and there is no `using System;` in there, so the compiler can't find it.

Second, `SearchEngineMainPage` doesn't have a constructor that takes a single parameter (in fact it doesn't have a constructor at all, so the compiler generates one for you, but that one takes no parameters, so it's still not good).

Comment: Did it work for you?? Did you go to the link in the question? I had copied the code from that example.... It also uses selenium drivers if that helps.

Comment: Did you read my answer? If you still don't get it, I suggest you pick up a C# book because both of your problems are beginner's C# mistakes.